# Predatory insect - what kind?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]I've seen several of these insects near my house in southeast Michigan this summer, including the one seen here feeding on a green bottle fly. What are they?

Comment: Probably Efferia or Promachus but I can't know for sure without knowing the size. How big was it?

Comment: @Praearcturus IIRC 2-3cm, but not positive. Feels like forever ago :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like a type of "robber fly" — compare with this image:
[image: From BugGuide — contributor Mark Swanson]

[BugGuide](https://bugguide.net/node/view/151/bgimage) is a great resource for identification of insects, spiders and their ilk.

Comment: Definitely correct! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!